# Joomla all menu items link to home

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I experience a strange problem. When im a public my joomla wont display anything but the home page on every link less the registration form. THe Url is changing but the pagedisplayed is the same : HOME!
When i log in  site works normally.
Also in debug mode site works normally.

What can i do? what settings to do. Mention i played with Cache and session settings and it is possible to messed it up.

I have SEF an rewrite mode on since the begging.

current settings:

CacHe settings OFF- catcihng disabled FILE 15
Session Handler database

ALSO have this notice on error reporting in development mode and only the second one in maximum

1. Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerPage::store() should be compatible with that of JCacheController::store() in /home/../public_html/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/page.php on line 20
2. Notice: Undefined property: JSite::$registeredurlparams in /home/../public_html/libraries/joomla/cache/cache.php on line 658
3. Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /home/../public_html/libraries/joomla/cache/cache.php on line 661

Comment: noticed that everything is ok if i disable system cache plug in WHy this happen? i want to cache my content. How to do this properly? i dont have knoledge on this

Comment: Which caching are you using? Also are you up to date with Joomla? I know ometing with $registeredurlparams was fixed not long ago.

Comment: joomla 3.0.2. currently im not using any cache. Can you recommend something?

Comment: You definitely have something set in global configuration, please check that.

Comment: I had a very similar problem I posted about just a week or two ago. I think there maybe something wrong with version 3.0.2's Cache?

Comment: 2 things come to mind: The $live_site variable in configuration.php, and RewriteBase in .htaccss.

Comment: it was a cache problem. Its been solved.

Comment: did you implement the menu items in the backoffice ? do you have a different menu for public access ?

Answer (score 1):

Just for giggles and kicks - in your config file - is your live site set to your home URL, or is it blank? make sure it should be blank. I have had some really weird things happen with SEF when that is not configured properly.